# Poor resolution / blurry geotiff raster layer on Geoserver with openlayers gui using wms

Tags: raster, geoserver, openlayers, wms, geotiff-tiff

I am having a problem with blurry geotiff raster layers served by geoserver and viewed in openlayers browser gui using wms.

I am hoping someone can point me in the direction of a fix.

- Openlayers is configured to use the same SRS as the geotiff for raster, ESPG: 4326
- SRS for layer confirmed to be projecting at 4326 in geoserver
- I have tried the following WMS settings:
- disabling jpg & png compression
- applying superoverlays
- with and without antialiasing
- all interpolation options: nearest neighbor, bicubic, bilinear.

The result is the same. blurry / low resolution image is present in openlayers web gui as well as geoserver openlayers preview.

one odd thing, the layer's resolution is correct on the last two step/zoom levels. IT looks the same in native preview and openlayers, But at all other zoom levels there is blur.

Please see screenshots for reference. The image on the left is gotiff in native image viewer. openlayers gui is on the right.

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

Comment: Did you add overviews to the file? If so, using which algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

The person who responded above was correct. It had to do with overviews. I used gdal extension in qgis to add overviews directly to the tif. The layers are crisp and clear now. Thank you.